# Error migrating from aws-sdk v2 to aws-sdk v3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
 NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
    at throwDefaultError (C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\smithy-client\dist-cjs\default-error-handler.js:8:22)
    at C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\smithy-client\dist-cjs\default-error-handler.js:18:39
    at de_PutObjectCommandError (C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-s3\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_restXml.js:5701:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-serde\dist-cjs\deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24  
    at async C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-signing\dist-cjs\middleware.js:14:20
    at async C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-retry\dist-cjs\retryMiddleware.js:27:46        
    at async C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-flexible-checksums\dist-cjs\flexibleChecksumsMiddleware.js:58:20
    at async C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-logger\dist-cjs\loggerMiddleware.js:7:26       
    at async DB.set (C:\Users\mrbil\Downloads\Projects\phsend\server\storage\index.js:53:5)
```

---

```
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.325.0",
"@aws-sdk/smithy-client": "^3.325.0",



const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand, DeleteObjectCommand, HeadObjectCommand, HeadBucketCommand, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');


class S3Storage {
  constructor(config, log) {
    this.bucket = config.s3_bucket;
    this.log = log;
    console.log(config)
    const cfg = {
      region: config.aws_bucket_region,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: config.aws_access_key,
        secretAccessKey: config.aws_secret_access_key
      },
    };
    this.s3 = new S3Client(cfg);
  }

  async length(id) {
    const result = await this.s3.send(new HeadObjectCommand({ Bucket: this.bucket, Key: id }));
    return Number(result.ContentLength);
    
  }

  getStream(id) {
   
      return this.s3.send(new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: this.bucket, Key: id }));
  }

  set(id, file) {
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: this.bucket,
      Key: id,
      Body: file
    });
    return this.s3.send(command);
  }

  del(id) {
    
    const command = new DeleteObjectCommand({ Bucket: this.bucket, Key: id });
    return this.s3.send(command);
  }

  ping() {
    const command = new HeadBucketCommand({ Bucket: this.bucket });
    return this.s3.send(command);
  }
}

module.exports = S3Storage;
```

I tried updating @aws-sdk\smithy-client to solve this error, but i am stuck onto it. please help!

Comment: Did you have the chance to use the migrator from v2 to v3? I was able to use and it helped me a little bit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-js-codemod

Comment: @thiago , no sir , thanks for the help, let me try it.